# Disabling Start hardware button on windows 8 Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Am creating an application where i need to disable/override the hardware start button on a windows 8 tab.Can anyone write down a small piece of code and list the libraries that i have to refer?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You will likely get better responses instead of downvotes (I haven't downvoted since you are new) if you demostrate you have an understanding of the problem at hand, and that you have made an effort to work out the solution for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that.  It isn't something you can control from an app.
Also, even if you do manage to find some way to do it, you will almost certainly fail certification and your app won't be available in the store.

Comment: I just wanted to know whether its possible for me to lockdown a form so the user is not able to switch to or navigate to the home screen even if he clicks on the start or back button.The only way he can do so is by clicking on the next button on the form which will redirect him to some other form and then he can use the Start hardware button to navigate to the home screen.

Comment: I understand your requirement, but this is totally forbidden in a Windows Phone app.  The central belief in this ecosystem is that the user should be in control of his/her device so restricting the ability to go to the home screen is disallowed.

Answer (score 3):

First welcome to stack overflow. People here are awesome at helping you in a pinch. That said, if you want someone to just lay down fresh code for you you're better off at http://www.freelancer.com

Also, windows phone OS is one of the most secure, consistent OS on the market. Manipulation of the start button destroys this consistency and is prohibited. I would suggest reviewing the MSDN documentation for certification requirements.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184843(v=vs.105).aspx